# Want to Call Javascript in FCKeditor code

Tags: php, fckeditor

I want to call onblur function in FCKeditors.

Here is the my code.

```
  <?php
  $oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor('conf_emailtext['.$this->escape($data->conf_id).']') ;  
  $oFCKeditor->BasePath = $this->baseUrl().'/FCKeditor/' ;
  $oFCKeditor->Value =  $this->arrMailList[$i]['conf_emailtext'];
  $oFCKeditor->Height ='400px';
  $oFCKeditor->Width ='650px';
  $oFCKeditor->Create() ;
  ?>
```

Can anybody help me to sort out this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Kanji

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think so, it's possible to set in PHP. However you can achieve this using Javascript on HTML/template page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function FCKeditor_OnComplete( editor_instance)
{
   editor_instance.Events.AttachEvent( 'OnFocus', DoSomething ) ;
   editor_instance.Events.AttachEvent( 'OnBlur', DoSomething1 ) ;
}
</script>
```

Comment: How to pass value in DoSomething1 javascript function from FCKeditor code?

Comment: What value you want to pass?. More specific description about JS API you can find at http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/JavaScript_API

Comment: I want to pass 3 values. 1st Value of the FCKeditor, field name and id from the database.

Comment: Can i set aboove javascript in PHP?